# How to convert a number to string via unary operator in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

In Javascript, to convert strings to numbers we can do:

```
var str = "1" // "1" as string 
var num = +str  //  1  as number
```

Which operator I can use for doing the same in reverse similar to `number.toString()`? ie converting a number to a string

```
var num = 1             //  1  as a number 
var str = (operator)num // "1" as a string
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no "bitwise operator" that returns a string, also the "unary plus operator" is not bitwise. The closest versions would be:

```
 "" + 12
 `${12}`
```

Comment: "string concatenation" (top) and "template literal" (bottom)

Comment: @dragonKnight here is a full list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: @DragonKnight that's not an operator, it's just [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (AKA String interpolation) `<-` the second approach.

Comment: @ele it is, the `+` is a string concatenation operator according to MDN

Comment: @JonasWilms my comment is about the template literal.

Comment: what about the name of the plus sign before string to make it integer? `var num = +a  //  1  as number 
`

Comment: @dragonKnight thats the "unary plus operator" mentioned in the answer